# UIStepper tintColor not functioning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, tintcolor

I recently updated my project to iOS 7.1. During the switch, nothing changed except for one thing. In iOS 7, within my app delegate, I set my window tint color to blue. On a view controller, I have a UIStepper that I set the tint color as white in both Interface Builder and programmatically. Prior to updating, the stepper was tinted white while everything else was blue as it should have been. After being updated, however, the stepper remains the tint color of my app. Does anybody know why this happens, or how to fix it? Any insight is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried this (set stepper's tint color to white in storyboard - of course I had to have a dark colored view behind it) and it worked perfectly. So something else is going on that you are concealing.

Comment: Hmmm. I wouldn't say concealing, I just don't want to overflow people with unnecessary information. Those are the only things that I can see influencing the tintColor though.

Comment: If it helps, the UIStepper is the third subview in the view hierarchy. UIViewController>UIView>UIView>UIStepper.

Comment: Yes, that's how I have it. Here's a screen shot: http://imgur.com/YlDx0Ld I've set the window's tint color to red just so you know I'm changing the tint color in code; that's why the button is red. But the stepper is white, as set in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by clicking on my UIStepper in Interface Builder, clicking on the first pane of the item inspector, and changing global tint to white.